# Visual MFC 2015 - Having problem with stringstream with a CString japanese

Tags: visual-c++

I am struggling with using streamstring for a variable Cstring which contains japanese character. I have tried to use imbue or even setlocate method but it does not work, the result when I dubug "ss" is always ???? chracter. Please help!

```
CString m_strPath = L"適当";
std::stringstream ss;
ss.imbue(std::locale("Japanese"));
ss << m_strPath;
```

I want ss contain "適当" too.

Comment: I tried out the code in rextester. It appears to be working perfectly. You can see it in the following link:
https://rextester.com/EXVGP65732

I think the issue may with the IDE that you are using. Some IDEs (like codeblocks) don't support japanese text by default and saves the source code as ansii which turns `適当` into `????`

Comment: Dear Tanmoy, thank you so much for your help. Yes this site run out with correct result even you removed "ss.imbue(std::locale("Japanese"));" but in my IDE (Visual Studio 2015) it is always ????

Comment: Are you using windows or a Linux machine?

Comment: Can you use `std::wstringstream`?

Comment: Dear Tanmoy and Phil, I am using window and VS 2015. I have also tried with wstringstream but it still does not work also. Do I need to overload << operator for CString type?

Comment: @PhilBrubaker his problem is occurring because of his IDE, not his code. I faced the same problem once, but I can't remember exactly how I solved it. I'll try searching online. If I can find the solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: @ChungTran Assuming these are Unicode characters, make sure you're using the wide-string extraction operator for `CString`, e.g., `static_cast<LPCWSTR>(m_strPath)` and supplying it to something that can consume Unicode characters, e.g., `std::wstringstream`.

Comment: Dear Tanmoy and Phil, thank you so much for your time and helps.